# How can OpenMP's round robin scheduling hurt ccNUMA's performance?

Tags: multithreading, openmp, shared-memory, numa, multiprocessor

I'm trying to understand ccNUMA systems but I'm a little bit confused about how OpenMP's scheduling can hurt the performance.Let's say we have the below code.What is happening if c1 is smaller than c0 or bigger?I understand the general idea that different chunk size leads to remote accesses but I read somewhere that for small chunk sizes something is happening with cache lines and I got really confused.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,c0)
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
      A[i]=0;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,c1)
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
      B[i]=A[i]*i;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When A[] has been allocated using malloc, the OS only promised that you will get the memory the pointer is pointing to.  No actual memory allocation has been performed, that is, the physical memory pages have not been assigned yet.  This happens when you execute the first parallel region where you touch the data for the first time (see also "first-touch policy").  When the first access happens, the OS creates the physical page on the same NUMA domain that executes the touching thread.

So, depending on how you choose `c0` you get a certain distribution of the memory pages across the system.  With a bit of math involved you can actually determine which value of `c0` will lead to what distribution of the memory pages.

In the second loop, you're using a `c1` that potentially different from `c0`.  For certain values of `c1` (esp., `c1` equal to `c0`) you should see almost no NUMA traffic on the system, while for others you'll see a lot.  Again, it's simple to determine those values mathematically.

Another thing you might be facing is false sharing. If `c0` and `c1` are chosen such that the data processed by a chunk is less than the size of a cache line, you'll see that a cache line is shared across multiple threads and thus is bouncing between the different caches of the system.

Comment: @Micahel Klemm So if c0 is bigger let's say from the cache line and c1 smaller than c1(maybe less than the cache line) then do we have this problem with cache lines?Is that the false sharing?When multiple processors takes data from the same cache line?

Comment: Yes, false sharing can happen with both `c0` and `c1` and does not depend on the relationship of the two.  So, if `c0` makes the chunk smaller than a cache line, then you'll have false sharing for the first loop. Similar for `c1` and the second loop.

Comment: Hmmm I see,so it's better to use a big chunk size if pure static scheduling is not possible

Comment: That's not the right conclusion. You will have to use a chunk size (if you really need it) that matches what the system requires. Considering pages sizes and cache-line sizes, it does not make much sense for your examples above to use a chunk size of 1.  I'll leave it to you to figure out what a good chunk size will be, as this is going to be quite instructive.

Comment: Can I ask one last question If it's possible?I know that I'm being annoying but your advices are really helpful!What happened if the chunk size is bigger that the page size?It's the last question.Thank you!

Comment: So, if a chunk touches, say 4100 bytes, then a good part of the chunk will be in one page and a tiny bit will be shared with another thread that works on the next 4100 bytes. Right?  If the chunk size is a multiple of the page size, then no two threads work on the same page.  So, the larger you make the chunk size, the lower the chance of conflicting accesses on pages.

Comment: @spyros If your consider that the answer is useful, you should accept it with the check box on the left margin. This is the usual practice on this site and it is important to help future users with a similar problem find the right answer.